# Google Drive API push notification subscription 400 "parse error"

Tags: php, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to subscribe to get push notifications when a file changes in Google Drive. I've successfully implemented the Oauth2 procedure and receive an access token.

When I try to subscribe to the watch channel, I get a parse error which I assume means I have a mistake in the body of my request... but I can't figure it out.

Here are links to a couple of google resources that I'm working from:

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/changes/watch

Here's my code to request the push notifications (php):

```
    //subscribe to new watch channel
    $ch = curl_init("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1fEDEciN1h_7MZJmNxmgUF-xxxxxxxxx/watch");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                    'Authorization: Bearer '. $token["access_token"],
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                ));
    $body_array = array(
                    "kind: api#channel", 
                    "id: ".generate_uuid(), // Your channel ID.
                    "resourceId: 1fEDEciN1h_7MZJmNxmgUF-xxxxxxxxx",
                    "resourceUri: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fEDEciN1h_7MZJmNxmgUF-xxxxxxxxx/",
                    "type: web_hook",
                    "address: http://exampmle.com/test/drivenotifications/receiver/index.php" // Your receiving URL.
                );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body_array);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

And here's the error response:

```
"error": { "errors": [  {   "domain": "global",   "reason": "parseError",   "message": "Parse Error"  } ], "code": 400, "message": "Parse Error"}}
```

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated!

## EDIT

I also tried an associative array per the comments:

```
$body_array = array(
                    "kind"=>"api#channel", 
                    "id"=>generate_uuid(), // Your channel ID.
                    "resourceId"=>"1fEDEciN1h_7MZJmNxmgUF-xxxxxxxxx",
                    "resourceUri"=>"https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fEDEciN1h_7MZJmNxmgUF-xxxxxxxxx/",
                    "type"=>"web_hook",
                    "address"=>"http://example.com/test/drivenotifications/receiver/index.php" // Your receiving URL.
                );
```

But it resulted in the same error.

Comment: in the $body_array,  can you use a associative array in place of numeric key array

Comment: That was a good suggestion @JayRajput! I thought that might do it... but I tried the associative array and still got the parse error. (see edit above) Any other ideas?

Comment: Try checking the [Google Drive Push Notifications Playground](https://pushnotificationsplayground.appspot.com/all) to verify the correct steps specially the code implementation (though their [sample](https://github.com/googledrive/pushnotifications-playground) is python base code). You might also verify if you have done the required things before you can use the [push notification](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) like registering your domain and more. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `json_encode` the post data. Run `json_encode` on the `$body _array` before calling `curl_setopt` for `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Make sure that `$body_array` is an associative array before your run `json_encode` on it.

Comment: That's exactly it Jay!  I came to that same conclusion myself and came back to post the answer... it's always the simple things that you spend 3 days trying to find!! ;)  Thanks so much for the help!